# Meaning of "instead of a fallible extract for a book of miscellanies"

Tags: meaning-in-context

source: https://archive.org/stream/menbooksmountain00step/menbooksmountain00step_djvu.txt

> The really significant anecdote is often all that survives of a life; and such anecdotes must be made to tell properly, instead of being hidden away in a wilderness of the commonplace; they should be a focus of interest **instead of a fallible extract for a book of miscellanies.**

According to the above sentences, "Anecdotes should be a focus of interests **instead of a fallible extract for a book of miscellanies**."

I don't understand why a book of miscellany has falliable extract，and why anecdotes could become a fallible extract for a book of miscellanies. What's the meaning of the part in bold?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't _a fallible extract **from** a book_?

Comment: I was asking about **for** and whether it shouldn't be **from**, which would make more sense.

Comment: It is "for" although I have to say "from" seems to be better.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is saying that sometimes there is just one significant account (anecdote) of something that happened in somebody's life.

And this account must be highlighted. It must be told in a way that people remember it.

It must not be just an unreliable or incorrect (fallible) account of something that is included in a book that is full of all kinds of tales and other items (miscellanies), and which no-one is likely to find.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallible

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unclear.  The prose is indirect, but it can be understood from the context.

What is an anecdote? It is a short, often funny, story about a real situation that lacks careful research and so is treated as unreliable or rumour.  They are something that is falliable.

> John liked to tell an anecdote about meeting Paul McCartney.

Anecdotes often get repeated and can be published a books that contain lots of random information or badly written histories.

> This book claims to be a history of the second world war, but is mostly a collection of anecdotes about Winston Churchill.

But in your quote, the author says that anecdotes are important, and shouldn't be used just as extra and unreliable stories in history books that cover a wide range of topics.

Comment: If anecdotes are not written properly, they might just become or be thought as an extract from a book of miscellanies, other than from a biography. Is that the author want to say?